# Ubuntu GUI is broken after updates

Tags: 16.04, apt, dependencies, gui, desktop-environments

There were updates offered by Ubuntu and I installed them. After that the Ubuntu desktop GUI hasn't been working correctly and it freezes frequently. Moreover, instead of having the Ubuntu startup screen like below, only a blank gray screen comes, then on the desktop instead of wallpaper, only a black background is applied.

[image]

I also tried this `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` but get thee results shown below.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install `checkbox-gui`, then it gives another unmet dependencies error message, than another then another.

here is another screenshot of the Ubuntu desktop right now, 
[image]

Comment: If you're using a laptop/desktop that comes shipped with Ubuntu and you haven't added another OS for dual-booting, you may be out of luck. But, if you're using a dual-boot system or virtual machine on a Windows/OS X/Other Linux distro as the host OS, and if you're willing to wipe your Ubuntu data, then you might be able to create a new virtual machine or reinstall Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:**

Always remove PPAs with `ppa-purge`

**Whole story:**

Yesterday I wanted to try *KDE Plasma* and I installed it with following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

After hour I decided to switch back to *Unity* and remove *KDE*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --purge kubuntu-desktop
```

After login I was facing few problems, so I tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity`, but I was getting error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Some digging and I found out what cause it: removing PPA does not downgrade packages. The solution was to add it again and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

And then I was able to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` :)

Comment: Your answer matched my situation, but I don't understand how did you find that we should downgrade the packages. Could you explain further?

Comment: @zsf222 I am not sure, but I probably searched for keywords like "ubuntu", "ppa", "unmet dependencies" and found information that manual PPA removal is not safe, because packages are not downgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Below commands solve the my issue,

`unity --replace
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade -y`