# problems reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and purging gnome completely

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I purged gnome but when I'm at the login screen I can only log in with gnome: if I try to change shell everything is blank. Logging in with gnome lead to a black screen and I can't even open the terminal.

When running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I get the same results as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872428/ubuntu-gui-is-broken-after-updates/872813) I tried those answers with no luck. I also tried all the solutions and various command lines [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537263/reinstall-ubuntu-desktop-after-removing-gnome) without finding a solution.

I would like to get the standard Ubuntu shell, I don't use unity.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this on? 17.10 and newer, the default shell is GNOME, so purging it won't help. Are you saying you're getting the stock GNOME rather than the Ubuntu modified GNOME?

Comment: I'm on 16.04. Yes that's it, but I'm not getting either just a black screen and some icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run `sudo apt-get -f install` after this:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get remove gnome-backgrounds
    sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-backgrounds
    sudo apt-get remove gnome-session
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```